# How to add ambient occlusion to image texture to add dirt look

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders, ambient-occlusion

I am making a barn and need to the bottom of the barn to show dirt build o pin order to add an extra layer of realism and separate the ground and wood better. I have tried using ambient occlusion to no effect. The texture is an image texture which I have ran through a color ramp to make it red. I have attached the nodes as well as the render before and after I added the ambient occlusion node. As you can see there is not difference. Does anyone know how to add dirt build-up to an image texture (I have attached a reference)
The first barn picture is just the image texture, the second picture is with the ambient occlusion node.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, maybe share just the ground + one plank so that we can try (don't forget to pack your images)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I fixed it! I had to switch the color ramp to the color 2, not 1